# Completion handler and if statement within

Tags: swift

I wrote a function that I guess it should return a boolean , I'm using completion handler and switch and if statements within 
this is my code :

```
   class func login(username : String , password : String, _ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        let url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/login/"+username+"/"+password
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON{response in
            switch response.result
            {
            case .failure:
                print(response)
                completion(false)
            case .success:
                    if let dict = response.value as? NSDictionary {
                          let dict = response.value as? NSDictionary
                        let user = dict!["users"] as? NSArray
                        if user!.count > 0 {
                            print(user!.count)
                                                completion(true)
                                                }
                                            else {
                                                 print(user!.count)
                                                completion(true)
                            }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And I want to use it like this :

```
@IBAction func LoginBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        API.login(username: textUsername.text!, password: textPassword.text!) {
            success in
            if success{
                // if the function return true print(hello)
                //else print (type again)
            print("Welcome")
            }
            else{
                print("NO")
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: So whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: i don't know how to handle  boolean result sent , for example in my first code if it returns true i want to test it within the (if success)

Comment: @LouayBaccary so what you got in handler?

Comment: i want , if the result sent is (completion(true)) i want to execute a code , not if the result is success . in other words i want to execut the print(hello ) if the result is .success and completion(true)

Comment: I guess your code is ok as per your requirement. just make one correction completion(false) in else condition.

Comment: I don't see any issues with your code. Can you please pin point what exactly aren't you getting?

Comment: @LouayBaccary but in your code `success` represented the completion(true) means if you pass `completion(true)` then if condition execute in your code and if you pass `completion(false)` then false case execute.

Comment: i want my code to be like this 
if success {
if true{ print(welcome)}
else print(type again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all don't use `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift, use native types.
- Second of all **never** use `.count > 0` to check for empty array or empty string. There is an optimized property `isEmpty`

Your code is very cumbersome and there are a few redundant parts in it.

The logic is to return `true` if the `users` array is valid and not empty otherwise return `false`.

So the `success` branch can be reduced to

```
case .success:                
  if let dict = response.value as? [String:Any], let users = dict!["users"] as? [[String:Any]], !users.isEmpty { 
      completion(true)
  } else { 
      completion(false)                  
  }
```